# $setPristene is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a crazy problem.  I'm trying to run `$setPristene` on a form in angularjs, but when I do, an error is thrown, saying that `$setPristene` is not a function.  Now here comes the crazy part - I put a breakpoint on the line where it fails, and hover over the function call, and it says that $setPristene is inedeed a function.  Proof:

[image]

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: instead of adding screen add code with html please..

Comment: Yearg, that spelling!  That fixed it.

Comment: Did you referenced correctly your mainForm? It will need to have <form name="mainForm"> in template. Also, it might be that the script is executed before angular register the form, to quickly go around it, you could wrap your critical form part in $timeout of 0.

Comment: I did - the problem was that I just mmisspelled the function.  They I had inadvertently rewritten it in the chrome code viewer to see if that would work. Apparently when I made the edit in the chrome code viewer it was not implemented.  It did not get fixed till I changed the source.